# What am I missing? AJAX javascript JSON array parse to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to pass a set of already loaded images to a php file to then access a database to load more images unique to the ones already loaded. The javascript passes an array of the sources of the images, the php file performs a query to select all images limited to 12 not in the passed array. php then passes back the images as JSON objects so I can use JS to appropriately handle them.

**SUMMARY**

1. Get source of loaded images and put into a JSON array
2. Pass JSON array to php file
3. Perform mysql query to get more images
4. pHp puts images into a new array of images
5. Pass new images array to javascript
6. Javascript output images.

The javascript isn't loading the images, nor is it returning the test array I have in the php file of numbers. Why is it not working?

**JAVASCIRPT**

```
var imageArray = {};
imageArray.itemList = [];

function imagesLoaded(){
    var gal_img_thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("gal-thumb-image");
    for (var i = 0; i < gal_img_thumbs.length ; i++){
        var img = gal_img_thumbs[i].firstChild.getAttribute("src");         
        var new_obj = {'src':img};
        imageArray.itemList.push( new_obj);

        //imageArray.itemList.[i]['src']=img;
    }
}

function loadImages(){
    console.log("load images");

    imagesLoaded();
    $.ajax({
        url: "getimages.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            imagesArray : imageArray.itemList
        },
        success: function(images){
            for(var i = 0; i < images.length ; i++){
                console.log("image" + images[i]);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
$myArray = $_REQUEST['imagesArray'];

$images = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $image = array(
        "num" => $i
    );
    $images[] = $image;
}

echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

**FILE DIR**

- ..\Gallery\index.php
- ..\Gallery\getimages.php
- ..\Gallery\js\ajaxStuff.js

Comment: What is your question? Do you get any error?

Comment: alert(images) in success block and where you parse json in success

Comment: Check your firebug error console and see if you are getting any error.

Comment: I tried that, it seems strange because when I click the button to actually call the event the console doesn't log "load images". Which leads me to believe I have a typo or something.

Comment: okay I fixed the typo but it still doesn't work. Load images is displaying in the console.

Comment: does it matter if my php file is in a different file? See edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var imageArray = {};
            imageArray.itemList = [];

            function imagesLoaded() {
                var gal_img_thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName("gal-thumb-image");
                for (var i = 0; i < gal_img_thumbs.length; i++) {
                    var img = gal_img_thumbs[i].firstChild.getAttribute("src");
                    var new_obj = {'src': img};
                    imageArray.itemList.push(new_obj);

                    //imageArray.itemList.[i]['src']=img;
                }
            }

            function loadImages() {
                console.log("load images");

                imagesLoaded();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/test/test.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        imagesArray: imageArray.itemList
                    },
                    success: function(images) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            console.log("image" + images[i]);
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
            $(function(){
            loadImages();
            });
```

Comment: I just tried your example. What I did was just called the loadImages() function inside jquery document ready.

Comment: is there a reason for this?

Comment: It was the URL that was the issue.

Comment: the success call back is executing for me. 
console.log("images" + images[i].num);

Comment: THe reason why it was not working before was bcos the JS function got executed before the images were loaded. So we called the function inside jquery document ready

Comment: It worked fine when I took out the `$(function(){loadImages();});` It was the URL.

Answer (score -2):

try adding `async:false` so that ajax begins after the imagesLoaded(); call is completed

Edit: another thing you may try is to use `beforeSend: function() {..}`

Comment: Never do `async:false`, never.

Comment: Could you explain us why ?

Comment: If you do, you block the main UI thread, making the app unresponsive [going against the whole purpose of _Asynchronous JavaScript and XML_.

Comment: I mean even if this is a problem, effectively wouldn't break the example I have put above for testing. The php file is creating a dummy array of numbers 1 - 10. The php file should then pass the array back to javascript where in my console I should see 1 ... 10 listed. But all I see is "load images". So the success is failing. This is where my question lies. What am I missing? I've followed tutorials and everything but it still eludes me.

Comment: @user3012749 use the DevTool of your browser: check wether you have JS error [in the console], or HTTP errors [in the Network tab], it's either one or the other.

Comment: No errors. Literally, all it prints when I click the button is "load images". I moved the php file to the same location as the javascript file. Then I got a 404 error so I assumed the file location isn't an issue. But the echo might be the wrong thing to use. All the files are seperate. I have a js file, index.php file and the getimages.php. I think echo is chucking it out however it does but the Javascript can't catch it.